# Why is $("div > div") working differently than $("div").children("div")?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

I have a weird problem where I can't use the normal sizzle selector to correctly select something in jQuery:

These two lines don't do the same thing.

```
ele.children("div.a > div").addClass("badActive");
ele.children("div.b").children("div").addClass("active");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGvEu/1/

Comment: `children`, as the name says, only searches the *children* of an element. If you want to search all *descendants*, you have to use `find`. What you probably want is: `ele.find("> div.a > div")`.

Comment: You have to think differently. `children` selects every child and tests whether it matches this selector. In order for a child to match, it must be a `div` and have `div.a` as parent. I think it is better to think about these methods as *filtering* methods. `children` selects *all children*, `find` *all descendants* and then only those elements are kept that can satisfy the condition (the selector).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ele.children("div.a > div")` selects `div`s that are both children of `div.a` elements (from the `>` combinator) and `ele` (from the `.children()` call). It also implies that `ele` itself represents a `div.a` element.

`ele.children("div.b").children("div")` selects `div`s that are children of `div.b` elements, that themselves are children of `ele`. `ele` itself may be any kind of element, but it must contain `div.b` children, and its `div.b` children need to have `div` children.

As Felix Kling says in the above comment, you need to use `.find()` to search all descendants. This applies to your first case with the `>` combinator, as `ele.find("div.a > div")`.

Comment: Ow. My answer looks really hard to read with all those light-gray code highlights everywhere... can anyone help? ;)

Comment: Code is light grey here; that's just the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want is:

`ele.find("div.a > div").addClass("active");`

That uses the just a single sizzle selector and achieves what you want. BoltClock is right about why your two examples don't work the same. Another way to say it is: `.children()` only gets the direct children, whereas `.find()` will get anything in the hierarchy below the "current" element.